# Server side validation of Google Form copy-pasted into WordPress page

Tags: php, forms, security, validation, google-forms

I embedded a Google Form in my WordPress site by copy-pasting its source code into the page. Will I need "server side validation" for a Google Form?

Data submitted to Google Form is sent to Google Drive, therefore malicious code cannot harm my website - am I wrong? (Just to be extra clear...is data submitted to Google Form sent to my WordPress database?)

I am using some client side validation:

```
<input type="email" required="required" />
```

**Edit**

One more question. As long as the action has google's link

```
<form action="google form link">
```

then I am safe? So if I leave the action blank then it is no longer a Google Form, and data will be sent to my WordPress database?

Comment: Since it is Google's servers that receive data submitted from an embedded Google Form, you do not need (and in fact, cannot) validate it on your server. The data is saved to Google Drive, so it is not inserted into your WordPress database either.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Also, by embedding I mean I copy the code for a Google Form (aka everything starting and ending with a <form> tag) and paste it in index.php --- So as long as the action has google's link <form action="google's link"> then I am safe? If I leave the action blank then it is no longer a Google Form, and data will be sent to my WordPress database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would discourage you from copy-pasting the Google Form into your WordPress page, because then you run the risk of Google changing something in their form processing code in the future, so that your form will no longer submit properly. The supported way is to use the embed code provided by Google which uses an `<iframe>` tag to insert the form into your page.

To answer the actual question: since the `action` parameter of the `<form>` tag determines which URL the input data will be submitted to, if that URL points to Google's servers, then the data will not reach your server, and therefore you do not need to validate it on the server side.

If you leave the `action` parameter blank, the data will be sent to the current URL (your WordPress page), but since WordPress is not prepared to handle Google Form submissions, it will silently discard your data. Therefore it will not be saved to your WordPress database.

Comment: Regarding "run the risk of Google changing something...that your form will no longer submit properly" ----- If I test my form, let's say I submit "XYZ" into the Google Form and receive "XYZ" in my Google Spreadsheet, would this indicate that the form is processed correctly? ----- Therefore I would be able to tell when a google form is not being processed correctly? This question is to help me determine if I can skip the <iframe> stuff. (Currently, copy-pasting source code allows me to create customized forms)

Comment: Basically yes, if the submitted data gets into the spreadsheet intact, then it is processed correctly. If, however, submitting the form suddenly does not work anymore or results in an error, then you know there is a problem.